# iOS - View not loading properly in iPad when rotating

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have created a simple iPad application with rotation support. It has *two view controllers*. `First View Controller` is loaded automatically as `rootViewController` of the `AppDelegate`. It has a button on it which, when clicked, changes the `rootViewController` of `AppDelegate` to `Second View Controller`. The `Second View Controller` has a button on it which sets `rootViewController` back to `First View Controller`. This work Perfectly in Portrait mode. But when I rotate the simulator to Landscape mode, and click on the button on `First View Controller` to load the `Second View Controller`, it first displays the `Second View` **according to the device (*un-rotated*)**, and then rotates the display to normal (Landscape), after completing the animation. What is going wrong ?
The methods in `AppDelegate` to set `View Controllers` are as follows:

```
(void)loadSecondView 
{
    SecondView *secondViewController = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.window cache:YES ];    
    self.window.rootViewController = secondViewController;
    [UIView commitAnimations];     
}


(void) removeSecondView 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.window cache:YES ];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.firstViewController;
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you're wrapping two operations inside an animation block.

1. making a new view controller as the root view
2. showing that view in a curl animation

As a result, you see two operations during your animation.

1. new view is added to the window, and it's rotated based on device's orientation
2. curl animation makes the new view visible

You can fix this problem by applying the following change:

```
- (void)loadSecondView {
    SecondView *secondview = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = secondview;
    self.window.rootViewController.view.hidden = YES;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.window cache:YES ];    
    self.window.rootViewController.view.hidden = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)removeSecondView {
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    self.window.rootViewController.view.hidden = YES;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.window cache:YES ];
    self.window.rootViewController.view.hidden = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Basically, we're adding the view without any animation effect, and for transition animation, we're using view's hidden property.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mustafa. This makes sense.
I have implemented the solution and it worked like a charm.
Thanks.